# How do I find the centroid of a set of points in Sedona?

Tags: apache-spark

I have device pin data for a particular day. Sample below -

| deviceID | location |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | (2.13, 101.23) |
| 2 | (2.21, 101.89) |
| 1 | (2.88, 101.65) |

`location` column is of type `POINT`

How do I find the centroid the locations by the `deviceID`? I tried this SQL query but it returned a MISSING AGGREGATION error on the `location` column.

`SELECT deviceID, ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(location)) FROM table GROUP BY deviceID`

How do I resolve this issue?